# Final Grade Calculator in java

Tags: java, parsing, integer

This is a personal project, just trying to create a program to calculate my final grade and to the best of my knowledge I thought I did everything right, here is my entire program updated with working code:

**FinalGradeCalculator:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FinalGradeCalculator {
    public static final String readInFile = "MUSC110grades.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File(readInFile));
            String longString = "";
            while(readFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                longString = longString.concat(readFile.nextLine()+" ");
            }
            readFile.close();
            int indexQuiz = longString.indexOf("Quizzes");
            int indexConcertReports = longString.indexOf("Concert Reports");
            int indexMidterm = longString.indexOf("Midterm");
            int indexFinal = longString.indexOf("Final");
            int indexEnd = longString.indexOf("End");
            //Quiz
            String quiz = longString.substring(indexQuiz+8, indexConcertReports);
            String[] quizList = quiz.split(" ");
            int quizScores = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<quizList.length;i++)
                quizScores += Integer.parseInt(quizList[i]);
            //Concert Report
            String cR = longString.substring(indexConcertReports+16, indexMidterm);
            String[] cRList = cR.split(" ");
            int cRScores = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<cRList.length;i++)
                cRScores += Integer.parseInt(cRList[i]);
            //Midterm
            String midterm = longString.substring(indexMidterm+8, indexFinal-1);
            int midtermScores = Integer.parseInt(midterm);
            //Final
            String finals = longString.substring(indexFinal+6, indexEnd-1);
            int finalsScores = Integer.parseInt(finals);

            double quizAvg = Math.ceil(quizScores/quizList.length);
            System.out.println("Your Quiz Average is " + quizAvg);
            double cRAvg = Math.ceil(cRScores/cRList.length);
            System.out.println("Your Concert Report Average is " + cRAvg);
            double midtermGrade = Math.ceil(midtermScores);
            System.out.println("Your Midterm Grade is " + midtermGrade);
            double finalsGrade = Math.ceil(finalsScores);
            System.out.println("Your Finals Grade is " + finalsGrade);
            double totalGrade = Math.ceil(cRAvg*0.2 + quizAvg*0.35 + midtermGrade*0.2 + finalsGrade*0.25);
            System.out.println("Your Total Grade is " + totalGrade);

            if(totalGrade >= 90)
                System.out.println("Your final grade is A");
            else if(totalGrade >= 85)
                System.out.println("Your final grade is B+");
            else if(totalGrade >= 80)
                System.out.println("Your final grade is B");
            else if(totalGrade >= 75)
                System.out.println("Your final grade is C+");
            else if(totalGrade >= 70)
                System.out.println("Your final grade is C");
            else if(totalGrade >= 65)
                System.out.println("Your final grade is D+");
            else if(totalGrade >= 60)
                System.out.println("Your final grade is D");
            else
                System.out.println("your final grade is F");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program it gives me a number format exception: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "70 "`. here is the text file:

**MUSC110grades.txt:**

```
Quizzes
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
0
0
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
0
0
100
100
0
0
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
Concert Reports
100
100
90
90
Midterm
72
Final
70
End
```

Now I've looked up what a number format exception is but I don't understand why the number `50` is not an integer. I need help solving this issue, it may have something to do with the index's maybe. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes from the fact that there is a space after `50`. Can you check that ?

Comment: There is not a space after `50` but I tried using `int finalsScores = Integer.parseInt(finals.trim());` and that worked.

Comment: Which means there was a space :) See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()